Measure to calculate occurrence of a character in Power BI
I have a table named srs_cap with columns that contain decision information (cap_dec1, cap_dec2, cap_dec3) and the corresponding dates when those decisions were made (cap_decd, cap_dcd2, cap_dcd3).
cap_dec1 corresponds to cap_decd,
cap_dec2 corresponds to cap_dcd2,
cap_dec3 corresponds to cap_dcd3.

The logic is as follows: Identify the most recent decision date from cap_decd, cap_dcd2, and cap_dcd3 that is on or before same date last year. If the corresponding decision (cap_dec1, cap_dec2, or cap_dec3) has the value 'C', then count the entries in cap_stuc.
i am using the below two measure one to check occurrence of C and second one to check U
Conditional_Count =
SUMX(
    srs_cap,
    VAR CutoffDate = DATE(YEAR(TODAY()) - 1, MONTH(TODAY()), DAY(TODAY()))
    VAR Date1 = IF(AND([cap_decd] <= CutoffDate, NOT(ISBLANK([cap_decd]))), [cap_decd], BLANK())
    VAR Date2 = IF(AND([cap_dcd2] <= CutoffDate, NOT(ISBLANK([cap_dcd2]))), [cap_dcd2], BLANK())
    VAR Date3 = IF(AND([cap_dcd3] <= CutoffDate, NOT(ISBLANK([cap_dcd3]))), [cap_dcd3], BLANK())
    VAR MostRecentDate = MAXX(
        { Date1, Date2, Date3 },
        [Value]
    )
    VAR IsDecisionC = SWITCH(
        TRUE,
        MostRecentDate = Date1 && [cap_dec1] = "C", 1,
        MostRecentDate = Date2 && [cap_dec2] = "C", 1,
        MostRecentDate = Date3 && [cap_dec3] = "C", 1,
        0
    )
    RETURN
        IF(IsDecisionC = 1, 1, 0)
)

The same logic but now we are looking for U instead of C
UnConditional_Count =
SUMX(
    srs_cap,
    VAR CutoffDate = DATE(YEAR(TODAY()) - 1, MONTH(TODAY()), DAY(TODAY()))
    VAR Date1 = IF(AND([cap_decd] <= CutoffDate, NOT(ISBLANK([cap_decd]))), [cap_decd], BLANK())
    VAR Date2 = IF(AND([cap_dcd2] <= CutoffDate, NOT(ISBLANK([cap_dcd2]))), [cap_dcd2], BLANK())
    VAR Date3 = IF(AND([cap_dcd3] <= CutoffDate, NOT(ISBLANK([cap_dcd3]))), [cap_dcd3], BLANK())
    VAR MostRecentDate = MAXX(
        { Date1, Date2, Date3 },
        [Value]
    )
    VAR IsDecisionU = SWITCH(
        TRUE,
        MostRecentDate = Date1 && [cap_dec1] = "U", 1,
        MostRecentDate = Date2 && [cap_dec2] = "U", 1,
        MostRecentDate = Date3 && [cap_dec3] = "U", 1,
        0
    )
    RETURN
        IF(IsDecisionU = 1, 1, 0)
)

But getting incorrect results, Sample data along with correct output and measure output is provided below, I am considering today data as cut off date (08/11/2023)

